# CakePHP Shell: Fatal error: Call to undefined function xcache_isset()

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, dreamhost, xcache

I am having a strange problem right now with CakePHP. I haven't used the shell in sometime since I enabled XCache on Dreamhost, and now when I try to use the CakePHP Shell script I have, I get this error.. 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function  xcache_isset()

However, I don't have any errors/problems with my site, except for the shell it seems..

Any ideas how to fix this would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Dreamhost, the solution to this is going to VPS => Configure Server, then setting PHP Cache to active. This will enable XCache server wide rather just on one domain. Then CakePHP will work find through the shell.

Answer (score 2):

PHP as isapi module and CLI have different config files. You need to specify to the same one or fix the CLI's one so it loads the XCache extension.

More detailed info you can get at your provider support.